# C# Filter IQueryable with ToString

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have an `IQueryable<SomeObject> query` which contains a property Value which is a `double`.

I want to filter it by a string that has dot thousands separator comma before decimal (european).

I've tried the following: `query.Where(q => q.Value.ToString("#,##0.00").StartsWith(someValue)`

The issue is that it couldnt be translated: `Translation of method 'double.ToString' failed. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.`

For my case it is not possible to convert to client evaluation as still need to apply form several other filters to my query. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What ORM?

Comment: MSSQL with Entity Framework

Comment: Seems to be a  XY Problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: That's *definitely* an XY problem. There's no reason to ever treat numbers, especially floating point numbers, as strings. Numbers are digital values, they have no separators. Parse `someValue` into the correct type and compare with it

Comment: What does `value` contain and why are you trying to treat it as a string at all? What are you searching for? If you want to find amounts or prices in a range, use a *double* parameter. Even better, use `decimal` in C# and `numeric` with a specific scale in the database. `double` can cause rounding errors

Comment: What application are you building? Most numeric controls return a number, not a string. For example, [NumericUpDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) returns a `decimal. .NET's `double.Parse` or `decimal.Parse` will use the current thread's locale. In dekstop applications that's the user's locale, so `decimal.Parse(txtInput.Text)` will use the correct settings automatically. You can pass a different locale specifically too. In web aps, the locale can be configured at many levels and even track the browser's locale

Comment: `value` is a Double. Im trying to treat it like a string because im NOT trying to find amounts or prices in a range, but amounts that start with the sequence of numbers that `someValue` consists of.

Im building a search with some filtering where someValue is the amount to filter by. If your input 2 every amount that starts with 2 should show up. If you input 23 every amount that starts with 23 should show up.

Comment: Sorry, I dont really care how you think it should work. I am trying to achieve the behavior my customer desires.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ToString()` doesnt accept your string format.

It is not the best idea to stringify double, especially when it is a number which is perfect type to use logic with.

Change your:

```
query.Where(q => q.Value.ToString("#,##0.00").StartsWith(someValue);
```

to

```
query.Where(q => q.Value >= someValue && q.Value < someMinimalValue);
```

then, you want to take values that "starts with" so with values (for `2.11`) it can be:

```
query.Where(q => q.Value >= 2.11 && q.Value < 2.12);
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is I really want to use StartsWith as when the user inputs "3" it should display any result that starts with "3". If i'm correct your example will only work once the user has input the full number the user is interested in filtering for.

Comment: Then what about using `Contains()`? Contains searches for the specified string into the entity therefore if the user inputs 3 Ef will get all the records with 3 inside @yyy-t

Comment: @yyy-t the bug is trying to treat numbers as strings in the first place. This prevents the use of indexes and can *very easily* result in bad results, if `someValue` doesn't have the format you assumed.

Comment: It is okay for bad/no results to appear if someValue doesnt have the format assumed. That is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to format a double as a string within the LINQ to Entities query, and that's causing a translation issue. The `ToString` method you're using is not translatable to SQL, which is why it's suggesting client evaluation.

Instead of using `ToString` within the query, you can try using the `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` method. Here's an example:

```
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

// ...

query.Where(q => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?)q.Value).Trim().StartsWith(someValue))
```

This should help in converting the double to a string in a way that can be translated to SQL. The `Trim` is added to remove trailing spaces that might be introduced during conversion.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you want. I just added 'AsQueryable()' before 'Where':

```
    class Program
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public double Value { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string someValue = "2.3";

            List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person()
                {
                    Name = "Jack",
                    Value = 2.3
                },
                 new Person()
                {
                    Name = "Nina",
                    Value = 3
                },
                  new Person()
                {
                    Name = "Woody",
                    Value = 2.36589
                },
                   new Person()
                {
                    Name = "David",
                    Value = 10
                   },
            };

            IQueryable<Person> query = people.AsQueryable().Where(q => q.Value.ToString("#,##0.00").StartsWith(someValue));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think he works with EFCore which makes it a little bit different

Comment: No, It's not for EFCore. Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Entity Framework is not able to translate the `ToString` method with a custom format into a SQL query. To work around this, you can consider formatting the value before applying the filter. For Example:

```
string formattedSomeValue = someValue.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", ".");
query = query.Where(q => q.Value.ToString("#,0.00").StartsWith(formattedSomeValue));
```

In this code, `formattedSomeValue` is created by replacing the European style thousands separator (dot) with an empty string and the European style decimal separator (comma) with a dot. This way, you can perform the filtering in a way that can be translated by Entity Framework.

Make sure to replace the query variable with the filtered result, as LINQ methods like `Where` return a new `IQueryable` object.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This won't remove the original error (using ToString in the first place), but it *will* introduce more bugs - half the world uses `.` as the *thousand* separator. Replacements like these are behind the 100K billing errors we read in the news from time to time

Comment: Thanks but this wont help. The problem lies with the ToString() operator.